# Infinite subgroups of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ where each element has finite order

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finitely-generated

I am interested in finite subgroups of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)\cong\text{Aut}\,\mathbb C(x)$.

> Let $G\subset\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ be finitely generated such that each $g\in G$ has finite order. Is $G$ necessarily finite?

The "finitely generated" hypothesis is necessary here, since $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}e^{2\pi i t} & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}:t\in\mathbb Q\right\}$$ is an infinite subgroup where each element has finite order.

This problem *without* the restriction of being a subgroup of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is known as the Burnside problem, for which Golod and Shafarevich came up with a counter-example in 1964. However, my instinct is that $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ wouldn't have such weird subgroups.

More generally, is the question true for subgroups of $\text{PGL}(n,\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic words are "Selberg's lemma" (which states that a finitely generated matrix group has a torsion free subgroup of finite index).

Comment: So does the following argument work? You can lift $G$ to a subgroup $\overline G$ of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb C)\subset\text{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$ which is still a finitely generated, torsion, infinite group. Selberg's lemma gives a finite-index subgroup $H\subset\overline G$, so in particular there is an element $\sigma\in H$ of infinite order, a contradiction.

Comment: @KentaS  Not the way I would phrase it. Selberg tells us that the finite index subgroup in this case is the trivial subgroup, thus the group is finite.

Comment: Thank you, that is a much cleaner way to phrase it, without needing to use contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

I found the following in Irving Kaplansky's book "Fields and Rings":

**Theorem G.** Any torsion group of matrices is locally finite.

Here, "locally finite" means every finitely generated subgroup is finite.